# Use GnuPG by default in Evolution

Tags: gpg, evolution

Is there a way to make Evolution default to encrypting messages with GnuPG?

It'd be acceptable if Evolution complains and refuses to send unencrypted emails to addresses for which it lacks a gpg key, but it should *never* send an unencrypted email to an address for which it posseses a gpg key.

Is there even a visible indication that warns the user when messages are not encrypted?